# forwardInvocation vs class_addMethod

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my implementation, I have the choice of using class_addMethod to create new methods in runtime, or I can rely on forwardInvocation/NSProxy.  When both approaches are available as solutions, which way would you prefer and how do you determine?

Comment: Note that forwardingTargetForSelector also exists

Comment: They apply to different situations. forwardingTarget is clean and pretty fast but not necessarily as flexible.

Comment: In what situation would you use forwardingTarget?

Comment: Setting up a straightforward "pass through all unimplemented methods" proxy. -forwardInvocation: lets you do fancy stuff like modify the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `class_addMethod`.

1. because it is much much faster than `forwardInvocation` (search method list, try forwardTarget, create `NSInvocation`, this is really the last attempt to resolve the selector)
2. it is more clear to add new method rather than handle all dynamical method call in one place.

Comment: Is there any downside to using class_addMethod?

Comment: the only thing i can think is it may have problem if you try to add method to existing method

Answer (score 0):

`class_addMethod` is the best choice. 
Because it can use method search cache to improve finding the match method address.

> Reference from : BOOK "Effective Objective-C 2.0" issue 12